# How to add integers to scenario and feature files from a table in specflow? Why do I get tan error

Tags: c#, api, specflow

When I change my scenario to use integers from the table I get the following error: Parameter count mismatch! ., all I have done is change the number in condition from 200 in the scenario which works fine but when I use , see code the error appears, here:

```
Scenario: When I submit my request to an API
    Given Given a valid input is used
    When the specific request data is meets certain criteria
    Then the status code for this test should be <ExpectedResult>
Examples:
    | ExpectedResult|
    | 200|
```

The step of this is pretty standard but the error lies in the feature file above:

```
        [Then(@"the status code for this test should be (.*)")]
        public void ThenTheStatusForThisTestCodeShouldBe(int p0)
        {
            //Do I get the expected status codes
            Assert.AreEqual(p0, 200);
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message? The code which you have posted should work fine. 
You get `Parameter count mismatch` if your binding method has more or less parameters compared to its regex. IN your case you have have one parameter in the regex `(.*)` and one parameter in your method: `int p0`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an Examples table, you must specify this as a `Scenario Outline`:

```
Scenario Outline: When I submit my request to an API
    Given ...
    When ...
    Then ...

Examples:
    | ExpectedResult |
    | 200            |
```